# use Vuetify's version of material-icons inside a vue.js web component target

Tags: vue.js, web-component, vuetify.js, google-material-icons

What is the correct way to include Vuetify's material-icons styles inside a web component, so that it is accessible in the shadow without any external links in parent (since web components do not have an index.html)?

I am targeting a wc like this:

`vue-cli-service build --target wc --name my-element 'src/components/mycomponent.vue'`

so, all css libraries/icons need to exist inside mycomponent.vue .

I've tried adding a link to the material icons inside the component's template

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons">`

I've also tried using the various instructions on this [page](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/icons#component-icons)

yet, nothing seems to work when the web component is included in an external page.  All you see is the letters of the icon name, not the icon.

```js
// main.js
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: 'md'
})
```

this does NOT work because the web component does not contain the Vue instance. (that is in the parent vue app).  And I am just exporting one .vue component.

I expect the icons to work inside a web component without any external dependencies in the parent.

Comment: Have you tried importing it from inside the `component.vue` like: `<style>@import "material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css"; </style>`?

Comment: tired it but it doesn't build due to dependencies missing.  says css-loader isn't there even if I install it.

Comment: you have to tell web pack to use css loader https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it to work by simply adding a link tag to the cdn inside the template tag of my mycomponent.vue file.

This is the only way I was able to get it to work in a child to another wc.  So my vue built wc is running as a child to a React built wc! Framework Agnostic!

Comment: can you share the code that you used to import icons

Answer (score 1):

I use Vue Cli to build the web components.  I did some research as to how to add css-loader.  It expects it to be in vue.config.js, like this ...

```
module.exports = {
css: {
loaderOptions: {
  css: {
    import:true
  }
}
}
}
```

Anyway, it still throws an error during npm build serve.  So, clearly this approach did not work.  With Vue Cli project, there is no webpack, per se. So, it is very confusing which instructions to follow,  Vuetify seems to be the issue.

Given Vuetify's instructions here, https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/icons#component-icons 
I don't know how to implement this using vue.config.js css-loader.

I need someone that knows how to add Vuetify's default material icon to a *.vue file that can be target a wc.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this for a few days now, and as far as I can tell, importing the icons into the app.vue file via a cdn results in a race condition in the built component, meaning the font is loaded but doesn't take effect.

The only solution I've found so far is to make sure that wherever you are using your component, you reference the icons there.

Again, probably not the best way, but it works none the less.

I do think that there is poor support for Vuetify within a wc made in vue at the moment. There are many other styling issues that occur like the paging select box appearing in a random location for a data grid. As far as I can tell this is to do with the position styling used by vuetify. A lot of elements use position:absolute which is fine when building to a native vue app, however targeting a web compoment adds wrapper divs which completely throws these elements off.

I'm short, unless I'm being a wally, I think the support for vuetify in a wc is poor at the moment, which is a shame because I enjoy vuetify as it abstracts the ui/ux away

Answer (score 0):

Having not used vue I might be give wrong advice:

When using a shadow DOM, the only way I've managed to get icon fonts (@fontface) to show reliably across browsers is to add a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/icon.css" type="text/css">` in the `<head>` of the HTML document.

Each shadow DOM/component will also need to import the same css file.

It does break the independent component idea unfortunately...